# How to fix 't[i].callbackFn.call is not a function' error when calling model.getProperties

Tags: javascript, async-await, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This issue has been resolved, though I don't yet know how. The section of code I have below doesn't actually seem to be the culprit since it wasn't changed before the error stopped being thrown. As far as I can tell, nothing else that should throw that error has been changed either, so I'm not sure what happened. If I figure out what fixed the issue I'll post it as an answer. For now I'll just leave this question up in case other people have this issue as well.

---

I'm creating a web app that uses the model viewer api from forge. I'm getting a strange error when calling model.getProperties in my code (where model is from Viewer3D.model), and I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to fix it. The stack trace in the error doesn't show any of my own code, only code from the api, but through debugging I've been able to isolate it to the model.getPropeties call inside a SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT handler.

The error is as follows:

```
TypeError: t[i].callbackFn.call is not a function
    at D.dispatchEvent (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:19:549356)
    at i (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:19:764740)
    at u.setSelection (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:19:766265)
    at i.handleAction (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:240200)
    at i.handleSingleClick (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:241136)
    at s.__invokeStack (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:229550)
    at s.handleSingleClick (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:229926)
    at s.mouseup (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:233391)
    at HTMLDocument.e (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js:30:233007)
```

I've wrapped the call to model.getProperties in a promise so I can await it in my async function. The function seems to work and return the correct value, but it also seems to asynchronously throw an error. I've wrapped the awaited call in a try catch statement but the error is never caught. Instead, the error is thrown just after the call "succeeds" but before any other calls are made.

I can see from the debugger that I get the expected values from the function, but the error is still thrown.

```
viewer.addEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
            onSelectionChange);

async function onSelectionChange(event){
    var dbIds = event.dbIdArray;
    if (dbIds && dbIds.length > 0) {
        await doSomething(event.model, dbIds[0]);
    }
}

function getElementProperties(model, dbId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        model.getProperties(dbId, resolve, reject);
    });
}

async function doSomething(model, dbId) {
    var properties = null;

    try {
        // This call works and properties is changed to the correct object
        properties = await getElementProperties(model, dbId);
    }
    catch(err) {
        // The code doesn't get here. The error isn't caught
        console.log(err);
    }

    // When the debugger moves on to this comparison, but before it is executed, 
    // the console shows the error
    if (properties != null) {
        // properties is not null. It is formatted as I expect it to be
    }
}
```

What is also strange is that this error is only thrown after one call has been made successfully. I use this to get the properties of the user selected item. The first selection will work correctly, but all subsequent selections will throw the error. Everything else works fine, including the portions of code that rely on "properties". Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace the error was thrown from one of Viewer’s click handlers and not any procedure that has to do with `getProperties` - is there any subsequent logic that might cause the error after the properties are retrieve especially any click events triggered?

Comment: I don't have any click event triggers specifically, but this call is inside a handler for the SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT which I imagine might use click events in the background.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with a live sample on jsbin or jsfiddle so I can look into things? By the look of the code alone the only issue I can tell is you will need to mark your `onSelectionChange` callback as `async` to be able to use `await` properly.

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately, I don't think I can. For some reason, when I came back to test everything this morning, there was no error. I haven't made any further changes in that section of the code, but I have worked on other portions. My best guess is that something else somewhere was throwing the error asynchronously and I managed to fix that issue accidentally. If I can figure out what fixed it I'll post it as an answer.